# Hibernate / JPA - Error when using createNativeQuery with @JoinFormula

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to use createNativeQuery but when I have a joined entity using the @JoinFormula annotation, I am receiving a NPE.

I have an entity which looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AppointmentEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -333387959619188900L;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinFormula("IF(status='','SCHEDULED',status)")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    AppointmentStatusEntity appointmentStatusEntity;
}
```

However, I am trying to do the following:

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM appointment", AppointmentEntity.class).getResultList()
```

which is causing this stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1224)
    at java.base/java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1218)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(TreeMap.java:374)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:343)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:277)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1043)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5166)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getString(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.hydrate(ManyToOneType.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3087)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1851)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1779)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1752)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1600)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:743)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1006)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:962)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2813)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2645)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2640)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1163)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:409)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy212.getResultList(Unknown Source)
```

When I remove the `@JoinFormula` annotation, I no longer get the error. Does anybody know how to work around this?
Thanks

Comment: @curiosa Unfortunately, that's not the problem. I had shortened up the code for sake of the post and it looks like I forgot to add that. I still get the error with the correct table name

Comment: Does adding, 'reference_name = status' in `JoinFormula` help?

Comment: @Davidm113021 What database and hibernate version do you use?